Insert point cursor "caret" has gone missing in text cells of Version 14.1 on Linux
In the last couple days my edit insert point cursor has gone missing when editing text and section cells.  It functions normally in input cells, equation cells, etc.  This is a fairly fresh install of both openSUSE Leap 15.6 and Mathematica 14.1.  I'm fairly certain the insert cursor was behaving normally when I first did the re-installation.  I am unaware of any changes I have intentionally made which would case this problem.  I do keep all patches up to date, but can't see any obvious correlation with recent updates.
Is anybody else experiencing this problem?
Version 14.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)
Release ID 14.1.0.0 (10597516, 202407163485)


A shot in the blue, try this

It happens under a pristine user account.

This started working without explanation.  There have been no patched installed, and no reboots since the last time it didn't work.  I used Mathematica for a minimum of 12 hours a day, every day.  I would have noticed if this had started working after a patch, or configuration change.  The only thing that may have impacted it was a switch from X11 to Wayland.

Add:  It's gone missing again, and I have no explanation.
